# Leverage swap space on Linux

Tags: simplifying-expressions, memory

Maybe this would be better suited on a different stackexchange, but I'll ask it here anyways in case Mathematica has some inbuilt functionality I'm not aware of.

I'm running `Simplify` on a huge expression which takes up a bunch of RAM on my laptop that only has ~10 Gigs of physical RAM. Im running Mathematica on Fedora 36 and can easily setup some SWAP space to be able to successfully run the calculation. However, I dont want to just create a SWAP space for the whole system to use since this would render the whole desktop session basically unusable since the SWAP would be on a really slow drive and the offloading to swap space is handled internally by the OS (as far as I'm aware)

Is there a way for Mathematica to somehow create its own SWAP space and use it as virtual memory over the course of a calculation? When the memory being used by Mathematica approaches the system's limit, my main kernel and Front End just crash to desktop (either being killed by the OS or some internal bug in the memory management part of the Kernel)

Comment: RAM is managed by OS. In linux you can add as many swap files as your like "dynamically" (i.e. increase on demand). In short there are 3 steps 1) create file (as root) say, 0.5Gb and fill with zeroes: dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288 2) format it as swap: mkswap /swapfile1 3) add it to system: swapon /swapfile1  To be sure check it it was added with swapon -s, or top or free -m and similar programs. After your notice that your need more, just repeat the procedure by adding swapfile2, ...

Comment: In general, however, this is "poor man's" solution, since my experience show it is almost impossible to do computations in swap. Computations use less that 1% of CPU speed... It is simply too slow. With fast disks (for example ssd) things  become even worse. In swapping regime the computer simply do not react to keyboard interrupts...

Comment: What you should actually ask yourself in a situation like this: Suppose the simplification found enough memory to terminate. Would you as a human being be able to interpret the result?